# How to Use nlsLM function together with one of the apply family function in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply, nls, tapply

I need a guide about how to do multiple regression columnwise.
I have a data frame where I want to get each columns fitting coefficients separately. So far I can have those results for only one column.

What I tried so far

1. Maybe assigning the result to a new variable

   (model.out1 <- lm(y1~x1))
   (model.out2 <- lm(y2~x2))

may work but I don`t want to write several fitting equations lets say about 15 and column names each time. that is not the elegant solution.

```
 2. using `apply` function 

aa <- apply(df[4:8],2,fit_function)


    fit_function <- function(x){nlsLM(x~ifelse(df$direc=="North"&V<J1, exp((-t_pw)/f0*exp(-del1*(1-V/J1)^2)),1)*ifelse(df$direc=="South"&V>J2, exp((-t_pw)/f0*exp(-del2*(1-V/J2)^2)),1)
    ,data=df,start=c(del1=5,J1=15,del2=1,J2=-5),trace=T)}
```

giving an error as usually we know

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) :    singular gradient
>   matrix at initial parameter estimates

Maybe separating those columns and fit each one of them and combine fitting coefficients may work. But I dont have an idea how to do.

here is the reproducible data for your check the validity
**df**

```
direc <- rep(rep(c("North","South"),each=10),times=6)
  V <- rep(c(seq(2,40,length.out=10),seq(-2,-40,length.out=10)),times=1)
  DQ0 = c(replicate(2, sort(runif(10,0.001,1))))
  DQ1 = c(replicate(2, sort(runif(10,0.001,1))))
  DQ2 = c(replicate(2, sort(runif(10,0.001,1))))
  DQ3 = c(replicate(2, sort(runif(10,0.001,1))))
  DQ4 = c(replicate(2, sort(runif(10,0.001,1))))
  group  =  c(replicate(1,rep(letters[1:6],each=20)))  
df <- data.frame(group,direc,V,DQ0,DQ1,DQ2,DQ3,DQ4)

library(minpack.pl)
```

Since I want to do fitting for all columns DQ0,DQ1,DQ2,DQ3,DQ4 I wrote down this function.

**fitting function**

```
 f0<-1e-9
 t_pw<-3e-8

nls_fit=nlsLM(DQ0~ifelse(df$direc=="North"&V<J1, exp((-t_pw)/f0*exp(-del1*(1-V/J1)^2)),1)*ifelse(df$direc=="South"&V>J2, exp((-t_pw)/f0*exp(-del2*(1-V/J2)^2)),1)
        ,data=df,start=c(del1=5,J1=15,del2=1,J2=-5),trace=T)
```

and to get fitting results inside of each group.

```
df_new<- df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  do(data.frame(model=tidy(nls_fit)))%>%
  select_("delta"="model.term","value"= "model.estimate")
```

how I can get the fitting results for DQ1,DQ2,DQ3 and DQ4 as table. maybe something like this is preferable

```
    group delta  value_DQ0  value_DQ1   value_DQ2  value_DQ3 value_DQ4 
1      a  del1   4.962564       *           *          *         * 
2      a    J1  14.666667       *           *          *         *
3      a  del2   3.496986       *           *          *         *
4      a    J2 -14.468551
5      b  del1   4.962564
6      b    J1  14.666667
7      b  del2   3.496986
8      b    J2 -14.468551
9      c  del1   4.962564
10     c    J1  14.666667
..   ...   ...        ...
```

**edit**
I found this [Help with lm and multiple linear regression](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-December/149194.html)
maybe I can do this by this

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10),z=10:1)
lm(x~., data=dat)
```

but when I replace if else part with DQ0 like above I got this error

Probably I`m missing some part. Can you give some clear answer about this_? nay help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have serous doubts about your approach. As you probably know, non-linear regression is an iterative process for which success depends heavily on the choice of the starting estimates. Not only that, but you must consider the possibility of local minima, and of course you need to assess goodness-of-fit, for instance by looking at the p-values for the parameters and testing the residuals for normality. Your model function is fairly complex, so trying to automate a process like that is unlikely to yield results at all, and even if it does you have no guarantee the results will be meaningful. At the very least you would need to plot the data vs. the model function for all cases. Just generating a table like this is asking for trouble.

Second, your example has several problems. Your model function depends on `t_pw` and `f0`, which, AFAICT you do not define anywhere, and `nlsLM(...)` is in package `minpack.lm`, not `minpack.pl` (I have not been able to find the latter anywhere).

Having said all that, I can see that you've put a lot of effort into formulating this question, and the basic issue: how to run non-linear regression against an arbitrary list of responses, with the dataset split group-wise, is interesting. Here is one way to do it using the `mtcars` data set. In this example, the grouping variable is `cyl` (number of cylinders), the response variables are `mpg`, `qsec` and `hp`, and the (very simple) model function is: `y ~ a * wt / (b + wt)`, with parameters `a` and `b`. So, for each cylinder category (4, 6, and 8) we model each of `mpg`, `qsec` and `hp` as a function of `wt` and determine `a` and `b`.

```
df   <- mtcars                # safer to make a copy
resp <- c("mpg","qsec","hp")  # response variable names
library(minpack.lm)           # for nlsLM(...)
get.coefs <- function(y,df) {
  fit <- nlsLM(y~a*wt/(b+wt), data=data.frame(y=y,df), start=c(a=1,b=-1))
  coef(fit)
}
coefs  <- lapply(split(df,df$cyl),function(df) {do.call(cbind,lapply(df[resp],get.coefs,df))})
result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(names(coefs),function(x) {
  data.frame(group=x, var=rownames(coefs[[x]]), coefs[[x]])
}))
result
#    group var        mpg      qsec           hp
# a      4   a 18.2436308 24.517564  98.80184109
# b      4   b -0.6655570  0.615073   0.42670565
# a1     6   a 14.2066098 62.179060  83.26572253
# b1     6   b -0.8599662  7.639224  -0.97768640
# a2     8   a  9.2212533 21.977518 204.59139171
# b2     8   b -1.4931033  1.213256  -0.08582505
```

In the code above, the function `get.coefs(...)` takes a vector `y` containing the response variable and a data.frame `df` containing the dataset, runs the regression and returns a vector of the coefficients.

The line `coefs <- ...` does most of the work. The inner `lapply(...)` passes each column of responses to `get.coefs(...)` in turn, and returns the result as a list. `do.call(cbind,...)` assembles the list elements into a matrix of coefficients with the coefficient in rows and the response variable in columns. The outer `lapply(...)` splits the original data.frame by group (cylinder in this case), and submits each grouped subset to the process described above. The result of all this, `coefs` is a list of matrices, one for each group.

The last line: `result <- ...` just reformats the `coefs` list into the table you wanted.

Comment: thank you very much for your instructive answer. now I am able to fit reproducible example that I have provided here. Sorry for not you to provide `t_pw` and `f0` values. I added them now. However, most of the examples that I checked do not focus on detail about the question that I asked here. so, as you indicated its a trouble some to get fitting coefficient from all columns since the model is complex and estimating starting values are also trouble some.

Comment: Now I tried your `answer` for may real data that have a same format I provided here. however, after 5 or 10 iteration `coefs` function is stopping as you predicted. Do you have any guide to solve this problem? such as estimating initial starting values in another function? you can use again `mtcars` example no problem. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not really. Generating a stable fit for a given response and a given subset of the data requires seeing the dataset and understanding the physics of the model. These are beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I understand. by the way as you can understand my question, I have a trouble with writing functions to process the data. since I cannot find any source of information I asked here. Do you have any suggestion about that? I mean some source for studying?